# Better way to declare regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I Have these regex for different country's,

```
var ukM = /(070|071|072|073|074|075|076|077|078|079)\d{7,8}$/;
var ireM = /(083|085|086|087|089)\d{7,8}$/;
var ireL = /(01|021|022|023|024|025|026|027|028|029|0402|0404|041|042|043|044|045|046|047|049|0504|0505|051|052|053|056|057|058|059|061|062|063|064|065|066|067|068|069|071|074|090|091|093|094|095|096|097|098|099)\d{7,8}$/;
var usaM = /(713|071|072|073|074|075|076|077|078|079)\d{7,8}$/;
var usaL = /(201|202|203|204|205|206|207|208|209|210|211|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|224|225|226|227|228|229|231|234|236|239|210|211|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|224|)\d{7,8}$/;
```

Is there a better way i can declare these? an a regex that would world for every country in the world?

Thanks

Comment: Different county's? `079` shared by two country's.

Comment: You can combine them all into a single regex with a distinct capture groups. The just check which group matched as a flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use character class to reduce the regex e.g.

```
var ukM = /07[0-9]\d{7,8}$/;
var ireM = /08[35-9]\d{7,8}$/;
...
```

Comment: You missed `Capturing Group`, `()` might be used for extraction

Comment: I think those groups were there due to alternation but can be added if OP needs it.

Comment: @Tushar, can you give me an example of what you ,mean , please?

Comment: @Tushar: No that's not correct. [See this working here](https://regex101.com/r/sL5iD3/5)

Comment: @Tushar Maybe `/08([5-9]|3)\d{7,8}$`

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on:

```
var ukM = /(07\d)\d{7,8}$/;
var ireM = /(08[35-79])\d{7,8}$/;
var ireL = (01|2[1-9]|040[24]|04[1-79]|050[45]|05[1-36-9]|06[1-9]|07[14]|09[0-9]\d)\d{7,8}$/;
var usaM = /(713|07[1-9])\d{7,8}$/;
var usaL = /(20[1-9]|2[12]\d|23[1469])\d{7,8}$/;
```